# Extract and concatenate titles in a list of string

Tags: python

I have a list of string with some *titles* inside, as Names, Places, etc.. and I want to extract them from the list and concatenate them if they are near (the words near are multiples). All the found names have to be inserted in a `names` list.

```
import re 
from itertools import tee, islice, chain, izip

l = ['hello', 'John', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'The', 'White', 'House', 'cat']

def iter_next(some_iterable):
    items, nexts = tee(some_iterable, 2)
    nexts = chain(islice(nexts, 1, None), [None])
    return izip(items, nexts)

names = []
for word, nxt in iter_next(l):
    if word is not None and word.istitle():
        names.append(word)
        if nxt is not None and nxt.istitle():
            names.append(word + ' ' + nxt)
print names
```

These are the results.

```
Results:
['John', 'The', 'The White', 'White', 'White House', 'House']
Desired Results:
['John', 'The', 'White ', 'House', 'The White House']
```

edit1:
I would concatenates words if they are **Title** (with str.istitle) and they are nears in the list ordered by default.

```
'you', 'The', 'White', 'House', 'cat' -> 'The White House'
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand the condition that you would concatenate them, can you explain it differently?

Comment: Added an edit to the problem description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your items using `str.istitle`. *Extend* a new list with the items in the group and *append* the *joined* group items if the group length is greater than 1:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['hello', 'John', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'The', 'White', 'House', 'cat']
names = []
for k, g in groupby(l, lambda x: x.istitle()):
    if k:
        g = list(g)
        names.extend(g)
        if len(g) > 1:
            names.append(' '.join(g))

print(names)
# ['John', 'The', 'White', 'House', 'The White House']
```